# Accessing an element in an XML file that has multiple elements of the same type

Tags: java, xml, xpath

The following is a sample of what my xml sheet looks like and as you can see there is a possibility that there can be multiple genres, actors, directors, and companies. How would I specifically access each one.

Preferably answer this question with XPath and Java but if you don't know those and have an answer then tell me what you know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movies>
<movie> 
<title>Seven</title> 
<actor>Pitt</actor> 
<director>Fincher</director> 
<genre>action</genre> 
<genre>drama</genre> 
<year>1995</year> 
<company>Cecchi_Gori_Pictures</company> 
<grading>79</grading> 
</movie>
</movies>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//read a nodelist using xpath
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```